# parallel processing

Tags: distributed, processes

We asked our dear friends, there are several idle systems that we want to use with our network of other active systems, 4 weighing software applications, in parallel processing and maximum processing power, to save time and money. The question is, is there any software that can handle all of the above? please help me. best regards.

Comment: What is the purpose of these software applications, specifically?

Comment: Hello, these software applications are : 1)AutoCAD. 2)Autodesk Inventor. 3)MATLAB. 4)CATIA. for running and processing.